# How to detect key press event and key hold down event without using pygame

Tags: python, keyboard-events

I am currently looking for a library that is able to detect/monitor the keyboard. 
My intention is to detect when a key is being held down and while it occurs something should happen.

Most SO posts suggest to use pygame, but i find it a bit too much, to involve a library such as that for this simple task. i've also tried with `pynput`, which resulted only detecting one press rather than a stream of presses.

any suggestions on how i can make this while loop detect a key is being pressed / held down...

My attempt with while loop:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    while key == keyboard.Key.cmd_l:
        try:
            print('- Started recording -'.format(key))
        except IOError:
            print "Error"
    else:
        print('incorrect character {0}, press cmd_l'.format(key))


def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.cmd_l:
        print('{0} stop'.format(key))
        keyboard.Listener.stop
        return False



with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The while solution make it stuck in the while loop, making it impossible to get out of it.

Answer (score 4):

One of the simplest way I found is to use pynput module.can be found here with nice examples as well

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False
```

## Collect events until released

```
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

*above is the example worked out for me and to install, go*

```
sudo pip install pynput (pip3 if python3.*)
```

Comment: I tried exactly the code you've posted, and it only detect the one press, when the key is being pressed and held down, is the callback function only being called once.

Comment: why don't you bind this snippet into a 
`while True:`
`try block`

Comment: You mean 
`while True: try: `

Tried it, but that result in being stuck in that while loop, and not getting out.

Comment: Added the code with the while loop @Nerdy.  If you try it out, you will see that it is being stuck in while loop.

Answer (score 0):

it's actually really simple. just a few lines of code, and its done!

```
from turtle import *

def a():
    print("key is pressed!")
    forward(5)

def b():
    print("key is not pressed!")
    backward(30)

listen()
onkeypress(a," ")
onkeyrelease(b," ")
```

you can replace " " with any key of your choice, surrounded in ""
examples: "a","h","e","Up","y"

Comment: Not that simple.  On my system, like many, *holding* down the key will come out as a series of presses and releases due to the key repeat feature of the operating system.  I.e. you can't detect *holding* down a key this way unless you disable key repeat at the system level.

Comment: @cdlane same, it becomes alot of presses. but its close enough, and sort of works!