# How can I hold down the keyboard key with python

Tags: python, pyautogui

Im using the **PyAutoGui** module, but I cant do a keyboard key hold. Who can say me what im doing wrong or recommend me another python module for keyboard control.

I tryed

```
with pyautogui.keyDown(key):
   sleep(1)
```

```
pyautogui.hold(key, time)
```

```
pyautogui.keyDown(key)
sleep(1)
pyautogui.keyUp(key)
```

etc. And **keyboard** module hasnt a key hold function too.

Comment: have you tried running the code in administrator mode?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: administrator mode doesnt help. im using windows

Comment: Not sure if you still need the answer. but you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66284097/pynput-and-pyautogui-cant-hold-keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pyautogui.keyDown('winleft')
pyautogui.press('r')
pyautogui.keyUp('winleft')
```

try running this code, confirmed 100% working, should bring up the ''run'' window

Taken from my own script, you can always use the

```
time.sleep(1)
```

function to make it hold for however long you need, just remember to

```
import time
```

at the start of your code (at least that's how i made it work)

Comment: i already tried it. I was sure it would work. maybe it's a glitch